# YQL: No JSON object could be decoded error

Tags: python, json, yql

Using python 2.7.3 to retrieve json data from yql finance. Here is the code:

```
import urllib
import json


response = urllib.urlopen("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.keystats%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'T'&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")

pyresponse = json.load(response)

print pyresponse
```

I'm getting the following error:

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: uhh it's an XML, [this](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.keystats%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'T'&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) link

Answer (score 2):

There may be an "s" missing in json.load. (json.load->json.loads)

For printing the json object you may consider using **json.dumps** to convert the object to string.

Comment: way better eyes than mine, +1 for noticing one character

Answer (score 1):

The default datatype for YQL is XML. To change this, set `format` to JSON.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.keystats%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'T'&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&format=json
```

[Clicky](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.keystats%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27T%27&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&format=json)

Moreover, the correct function is called `loads` not `load` (`json.loads(response)`).